# How to filter TWO strings in customAdapter of AutoCompleteTextView in android

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Im new to Android Development please help me. These past few days I've been working on application that involves searching of recipe by ingredient. So Ive created an interface that lets the user add an ingredient and the app suggests as the user types.

For many hours of searching here and there, Ive got the AutoCompleteTextView working perfectly, well at least f**or only one String**(the name).

But my problem is, my customAdapter **has TWO strings**(name and assoc) that I want my suggestions
to be compared into.

Here is my model class for my Ingredient Object:

```
public class Ingredient {

 private String code = null;
 private String name = null;
 private String assoc = null;

public Ingredient(String code, String name, String assoc ) {
    super();
    this.code = code;
    this.name = name;
    this.assoc = assoc;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}
public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setAssoc(String assoc) {
    this.assoc = assoc;
       }

public String getAssoc() {
   return  this.assoc;
}

}
```

And here is  my arrayAdapter for the AutoCompleteTextView

```
 public class CustomIngSearchAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Ingredient> {

private ArrayList<Ingredient> itemsAll;
private ArrayList<Ingredient> suggestions;

public CustomIngSearchAdapter(Context context, int viewResourceId,
                            ArrayList<Ingredient> items) {
    super(context, viewResourceId, items);
    this.itemsAll = items;
    this.suggestions = new ArrayList<Ingredient>();
    this.viewResourceId = viewResourceId;
}

   .
   .//getView Method
   .


  @Override
  public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            if (constraint != null) {
                suggestions.clear();

                for (Ingredient ingredient : itemsAll) {
                    if (ingredient.getName().toLowerCase()
                            .contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()) ) {                                suggestions.add(ingredient);
                    }
                }
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = suggestions;
                filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
                return filterResults;
            } else {
                return new FilterResults();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            ArrayList<Ingredient> filteredList = (ArrayList<Ingredient>) results.values;
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                clear();
                for (Ingredient c : filteredList) {
                    add(c);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }


    };
}
```

What I've tried already..

```
      //adding OR
for (Ingredient ingredient : itemsAll) {
      if (ingredient.getName().toLowerCase()
           .contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())  ||                                
           ingredient.getAssoc().toLowerCase()
      .contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {

                        suggestions.add(ingredient);
                    }
                }
```

But when I do this, the suggestions are not displaying..

Again, the arrayAdapter class is working fine for the **name only**

PS: I also tried making two separate FOR LOOPS...still unlucky

PS 2: please bare with my bad English . :)

Comment: where do you get your data from?

Comment: I got it from my local sqllite database.. I used it to construct instances of Ingredient Object

Comment: then see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830), all you need is to return the correct `Cursor` from `runQuery()` method

Comment: I looked into your link, my situation is different,.every row in the suggestion has the corresponding image and two text views, so I really need a customAdapter

Comment: and my adapter is not custom? if you need another `ImageView` just add it to your layout and handle in the adapter

Comment: oh forgive me, i dont know how to dynamically put an imageView and two textView to your SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: do you know what `res/layout/*.xml` is for? this is where you define your listview's item layout, just use `RelativeLayout` with two text views and one image view

Comment: yeah, I know that. I mean, how do I programmatically set the contents of every row inside your runQuery method

Comment: as i said: return tne `Cursor` from your sqlite db (SQLiteDatabase#query / SQLiteDatabase#rawQuery etc)

Comment: OK, I will try to do this now.. a thousand thanks btw,. hoping I can get this to work

Comment: Wow. a million thanks. I got it to work. One more question. how can I get the base ID of the selected item? (my "name" parameter is not unique so i need to bind the ID every row)

Comment: you need `_id` column in your `Cursor`

Comment: yeah, i did added _id.. but how can I get it when the user selects an item inside the onItemClick event?

Comment: see the last param passed to the method

Comment: oh, that's cool. A trillion thanks.